# Remove URI segment using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my url:

> http://localhost/BA/cookies-policy/register

I want that page to direct to :

> http://localhost/BA/register

...and so on if the above link is accessed.

I am not familiar with htaccess.

Comment: I am using redirect but my links are dynamic so i can use redirect for every link ,and also user has the permission to add new pages.

Comment: And why tag `php` in this. Tag sensibly please.

Answer (score 0):

Basic .htaccess 301 redirect rule for one specific URL:

`Redirect 301 /BA/cookies-policy/register http://localhost/BA/register`

Rewrite rule to match your needs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^BA/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ...I think OP needs that dynamically, not just one url re "...and so on" - Hard to tell though in fairness.

Comment: yes i need it to be dynamic.Basically "cookies-policy" is itself dynamic and i want a segment of url to be removed while routing.

Comment: Now it's dynamic and 301 redirected to avoid SEO damage.

Comment: its still giving a 404 after adding the rule

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .htaccess file in root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/BA/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this is  not working,it gives a 404 after redirection

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below, in your BA directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cookies-policy/(.+?)$ /BA/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: by adding this in htaccess it redirects to http://localhost/register and hence a 404

Comment: i am really bad with .htaccess

Comment: Try now I forgot to consider BA when I am writing the rule.

Comment: here is my complete file

Comment: RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^cookies-policy/(.+?)$ /BA/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: im sorry its not working for me,im not sure what could be the issue,but it is still redirecting to localhost/register out of the BA folder